# Image Upload Core MVC PHP: How can I append my successfully passed data in function in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Need to upload Files in core MVC: successfully uploaded. Now I am successfully passing my array of selected file from calling function to controller. How can I use that array in controller. Its showing : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in controller(i.e. inside foreach)

controller:

```
function gallery($real_name) { 
  /*echo "<pre>"; print_r($real_name); die();*/ 
  foreach($real_name as $k=>$v) { 
    // $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery SET image = '".$v->image."'"; /*echo "{$k} => {$v}";*/ 
    // /*print_r($sql); die;*/ } die(); 
    // if($this->DB->exeQuery($sql)) { return true; } } 
  }
}
```

Comment: file upload code:

Comment: controller: function gallery($real_name) {

   /*echo "<pre>";
   print_r($real_name);
   die();*/
   
   foreach($real_name as $k=>$v) {
    // $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery SET image = '".$v->image."'";
    /*echo "{$k} => {$v}";*/


    /*print_r($sql);
    die;*/
   }
   
   die();

   if($this->DB->exeQuery($sql)) {
    return true;
   }

  }

Comment: Put your code for reference.

Comment: database is MySQL, I am successfully getting the array of multiple selected images from calling function to the function in controller. Not able to append that in SQL for inserting those selected images in DB. I am using foreach to access it. ERROR MSG SHOWING: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\softcrayons\config\controller.php on line 122

Comment: put before foreach. `var_dump($real_name); die;` and show the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in Gallery function controller add:

```
function gallery($real_name) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery SET image = '".$real_name."'";
                      // instead of foreach just write above statement

            if($this->DB->exeQuery($sql)) {  //firing the query
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need loop here. Direct use `$real_name` with indexes to access file info.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO gallery SET image = "' . $real_name['file_name'] . '"';
```